# set aspect ratio of plot with dual y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, aspect-ratio

I want to set the aspect ratio of a plot with dual y-axis, but so far still at the `figsize` level, can anyone help to do it using other methods that more `axes` realted? like using the `set_sapect` or `plt.gca(subplot_kw={'adjustable':'datalim','aspect':'equal'})` Just start learning visualization using Python. Below is a toy sample. It would be great if the answer will also come with explanations for me and other starters to understand what's under the hood.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()

# data preparation
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,200,size=(100, 2)), columns=['col_1','col_2'])
df['group_l1'] = ['A']*50 + ['B']*50
df['group_l2'] = ['x']*25 + ['y']*25 +   ['x']*25 + ['y']*25

# naive benchmark plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df['col_1'])
plt.show()

# ~ 1, single plot
# ~~ 2） two series of data (dual y axis)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(df.loc[df['group_l1'].isin(['A'])]['col_1'])
ax.set_aspect(1) 

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(df.loc[df['group_l1'].isin(['A'])]['col_2'],'r')
ax2.set_aspect(1) 

plt.show()

# this won't work anymore, why? maybe because the two y-axis have different limits so python will get confused to set 
# a single ratio of two different y units to the same x unit

# a simple workaround in this case
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5)) # or any other ratio you want.

ax.plot(df.loc[df['group_l1'].isin(['A'])]['col_1'])

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(df.loc[df['group_l1'].isin(['A'])]['col_2'],'r')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes, the two y-axes may have different limits, in which case no unique data aspect can be defined mathematically.

Comment: Thanks, so basically, there is no workaround for such thing by using `aspect` related features?

Comment: For now the workaround is to limit the space available to the subplot, such that it will have the desired shape. [In the future](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/14917), there will be better methods available (Case C. in the link).